# Removing characters from a string in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, string

I have a function:

```
func IphoneName() -> String
{
    let device = UIDevice.currentDevice().name
    return device
}
```

Which returns the name of the iPhone (simple). I need to remove the `"'s Iphone"` from the end. I have been reading about changing it to NSString and use ranges, but I am a bit lost!

Comment: What if they've renamed their device so it doesn't end with what you're expecting. My device name doesn't match the pattern you're looking for.

Comment: Please disclose *why* you want to access the user's name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this:

```
extension String {

    func removeCharsFromEnd(count:Int) -> String{
        let stringLength = countElements(self)

        let substringIndex = (stringLength < count) ? 0 : stringLength - count

        return self.substringToIndex(advance(self.startIndex, substringIndex))
    }

    func length() -> Int {
        return countElements(self)
    }
}
```

---

*Test:*

```
var deviceName:String = "Mike's Iphone"

let newName = deviceName.removeCharsFromEnd("'s Iphone".length()) // Mike
```

---

But if you want *replace* method use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` as `@Kirsteins` posted:

```
let newName2 = deviceName.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
     "'s Iphone", 
     withString: "", 
     options: .allZeros, // or just nil
     range: nil)
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to work with ranges in this case. You can use:

```
var device = UIDevice.currentDevice().name
device = device.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("s Iphone", withString: "", options: .allZeros, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift3:

```
var device = UIDevice.currentDevice().name
device = device.replacingOccurrencesOfString("s Iphone", withString: "")
```

Comment: This code doesn't remove parenthesis... For ex: I want to replace this "\"(" by this "". But it doesn't work. It's like it doesn't recognize parentheses in strings. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Code**

//Add String extension

```
extension String {

    func removeCharsFromEnd(count:Int) -> String{
        let stringLength = self.count

        let substringIndex = (stringLength < count) ? 0 : stringLength - count

        let index: String.Index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: substringIndex)

        return String(self[..<index])
    }

    func length() -> Int {
        return self.count
    }
}
```

//Use string function like

```
let deviceName:String = "Mike's Iphone"

let newName = deviceName.removeCharsFromEnd(count: "'s Iphone".length())
print(newName)// Mike
```